# Protractor Timing Issues

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I currently have the following code in one of my test specs for Protractor:

```
.then(function() {
    return button.click();
})
.then(function() {
    return element(otherButton).isDisplayed();
})
.then(function(otherButtonIsPresent) {
    if(otherButtonIsPresent) {
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(otherButton)), getWaitTime())
            .then(function() {
                element(otherButton).click();
                return element(continueButton).isPresent();
            })
    }
})
```

When I use Chrome to debug using the `--debug-brk` and `--inspect` flags, I am able to pass these checks and resume as normal. When I run the same test without the flags, the test fails and stalls during looking for `otherButton` before trying to click on it.

I'm wondering if this is because during debugging, I set breakpoints and wait for the buttons to show up on the screen before attempting to click on them.

I need to make sure that this element is visible on the page before trying to click it and was wondering if there were another way if accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: Try using browser.wait() along with ExpectedConditions to make webdriver to until some specific condition. refer http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Answer as I can't comment yet.

You're basically mention it yourself: after you clicked a button you just want to wait until a next button is clickable.
Therefore your `.then()`-functions should start from the button it depends on. To me it seems, the three lined-up `.then()`-functions depend on the same condition, so after you `.click()` the first button, the second `.then()` gets immediately executed, not waiting the previous `.click()` to finish.

Therefore putting the `.then()` directly behind the relevant `.click()` and inside the preceding `.then()`-function, this should work:

```
.then(function() {
    element(button).click().then(function(){
       element(otherButton).click().then(function(){
           return element(continueButton).isPresent();
       });
    });
});
```

Or if you go with ExpectedConitions, you shouldn't need `.then()`-functions. Because Protractor should manage the ControlFlow, allowing you to write it without chained `.then()`-functions:

```
.then(function() {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(button)), getWaitTime());
    element(button).click();
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(otherButton)), getWaitTime());
    element(otherButton).click();
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(continueButton)), getWaitTime());
    return element(continueButton).isPresent();
});
```

[This nice post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/) elaborates a bit on asynchronous writing, but thanks to Protractor synchronous execution.

As alternative an example combining my both inputs, kind of double-securing the test:

```
.then(function() {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(button)), getWaitTime());
    element(button).click().then(function(){
       browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(otherButton)), getWaitTime());
       element(otherButton).click().then(function(){
           browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(continueButton)), getWaitTime());
           return element(continueButton).isPresent();
       });
    });
});
```